# Cant download MySQL software on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, terminal, raspberry-pi

I run the command below, I have tried `sudo apt-get update`, `--fix` flag and rebooting. I have checked my internet connection as well, any help would be appreciated.

**Command issued:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

**Output of the command including error:**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  default-mysql-server galera-3 gawk libaio1 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libencode-locale-perl libfcgi-perl
  libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl
  libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl libjemalloc1
  liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmariadbclient18 libreadline5 libsigsegv2
  libterm-readkey-perl libtimedate-perl liburi-perl lsof mariadb-client-10.1
  mariadb-client-core-10.1 mariadb-common mariadb-server-10.1
  mariadb-server-core-10.1 mysql-common socat

Suggested packages:
  gawk-doc libclone-perl libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl
  libsql-statement-perl libdata-dump-perl libipc-sharedcache-perl libwww-perl
  mailx mariadb-test tinyca

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  default-mysql-server galera-3 gawk libaio1 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libencode-locale-perl libfcgi-perl
  libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl
  libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl libjemalloc1
  liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmariadbclient18 libreadline5 libsigsegv2
  libterm-readkey-perl libtimedate-perl liburi-perl lsof mariadb-client-10.1
  mariadb-client-core-10.1 mariadb-common mariadb-server-10.1
  mariadb-server-core-10.1 mysql-common mysql-server socat

0 upgraded, 33 newly installed, 0 to remove and 72 not upgraded.

Need to get 19.5 MB/23.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 173 MB of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http/raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf mariadb-common all 10.1.23-9+deb9u1

  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:2 http/raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf mariadb-client-core-10.1 armhf 10.1.23-9+deb9u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

Err:3 http/raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf mariadb-client-10.1 armhf 10.1.23-9+deb9u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

Err:4 http/raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf mariadb-server-core-10.1 armhf 10.1.23-9+deb9u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

Err:5 http/raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf mariadb-server-10.1 armhf 10.1.23-9+deb9u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

Err:6 http/raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libmariadbclient18 armhf 10.1.23-9+deb9u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

E: Failed to fetch http
/raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/mariadb-common_10.1.23-9+deb9u1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

E: Failed to fetch htp
/raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/mariadb-client-core-10.1_10.1.23-9+deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

E: Failed to fetch htp
/raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/mariadb-client-10.1_10.1.23-9+deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch htp
/raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/mariadb-server-core-10.1_10.1.23-9+deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch htp
/raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/mariadb-server-10.1_10.1.23-9+deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch 
htp/raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/libmariadbclient18_10.1.23-9+deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get update` as well? Are you sure you have internet connection?

Comment: @szymon maszke, yes I have tried update and reboot as well, my internet connection is at 2 bars... wireless.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow btw. Please __always__ add as much detail about your problem as possible (no funny stuff like: `I have tried everything`) and be as specific as possible, so people don't have to ask and can focus on helping you out.

Comment: @ChrisForrence I purposely removed the colons because stack overflow wouldn’t let me post anything with more than 8 links, they are supposed to be complete links.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke thank you, I will try and be as detailed as I can!

Answer (score -1):

This error can be shown when the repositories are being updated, the general advice is to try again a couple hours later. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1344790

Comment: I see this got a downvote, the link I gave does indicate load on the repos causes this, as the original poster did not return, or appeared so, after an hour of asking the question there's a good chance this was just load. Be good if downvoters gave reasons and maybe added something.